# How do you add OrderID to this? I cant get it to display without getting a error on all OrderID sections

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant get it to display without getting an error on all OrderID sections. I tried adding it to the top and then the subquery and it errors saying ambouious column. How would be the correct way to do this?

```
TABLE SETUP: 
Customers Table:
CustomerID, EmailAddress, Password, FirstName, LastName, ShippingAddressID, BillingAddressID

OrderItems Table:
ItemID, OrderID, ProductID, ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, DiscountTotal, PriceTotal, ItemTotal, Quantity

Order Table:
OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate, ShipAmount, TaxAmount, ShipDate, ShipAddressID, CardType, CardNumber,CardExpires, BillingAddressID

CODE:
SELECT c.EmailAddress, MAX(OrderCost) AS 
LargestOrder
FROM Customers c
JOIN ORDERS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
JOIN (Select Orders.OrderID, ItemPrice * Quanity AS OrderCost FROM Orders, OrderItems
WHERE OrderItems.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)Largest
ON Largest.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY c.EmailAddresses
```

Comment: Nothing wrong that I can see. There is a spelling mistake in 'Quanity'. Is this the actual query?

Comment: @J.R. Theo wants to also show OrderID, which they can't add to the select list without also adding it to the group by.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ah, thanks.

Comment: Maybe rather than saying that you want to add the order ID 'at the top' which may not actually achieve what you want to achieve, would you be able to describe what you would like to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

It really helps for you to put some effort into a script that demonstrates your problem. That way no one needs to guess about how you defined things and the actual values you use.

Here is one approach based on my guess. Note "one" - there are techniques to achieve the same result. The cte calculates the total cost for each order just like your code attempted. Since you suggested top, I used that as well to demonstrate its usage. Grabbing the top first row based on descending OrderCost will get you the order with the highest total cost. Just join the cte to Orders and Customers to include the columns you desire.

```
with cte as (select OrderID, sum(ItemPrice * Quantity) as OrderCost 
  from @OrderItems 
  group by OrderID)
select top 1 Ord.OrderID, Ord.OrderDate, cust.EmailAddress, cte.OrderCost
from cte inner join @Orders as Ord 
  on cte.OrderID = Ord.OrderID
inner join @Customers as Cust 
  on Ord.CustomerID = Cust.CustomerID
order by cte.OrderCost desc;
```

[rextester here](https://rextester.com/JXFHG20903)

And everyone hopes that you are not actually saving credit card information - because that would be bad in many ways.

Comment: I missed `OrderItems` because it was hidden behind an old join, but there are multiple other issues with the query, I don’t see `SUM` anywhere, for example.